# Some code only works while chrome debugger is active

Tags: node.js, react-native, momentjs

I'm working on a react-native application and I'm trying to format a date using moment.

Dates look like "02-16-2016 09:04:23"

```
function formatTime(date){

  var formattedDate = moment(date).format('MM:ss A');

  return formattedDate;
}
```

Works fine if the chrome debugger is active. But if I disable it, all I get is "invalid date"

Same thing with a decoding function I'm using

```
var that = this;
MessagesService.getMessageBody(selectedMessage)
    .then(function(messageBody){

        var decodedData = window.atob(messageBody.messages);

        that.setState({
          messageBody: decodedData
        })
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Displaying the decoded data with

```
<Text> Body: {this.state.messageBody} </Text>
```

and displaying the date with

```
<View style = {[MessageStyles.senderItem, MessageStyles.date]}>
       <Text>
          {this.formatTime(message.createDateTime)}
       </Text>
</View>
```

Maybe this is a bad way to do this in react native? Still learning so I could be doing some bad practice.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just the snippets.  As it is, it's difficult to help because we can't easily reproduce the issue without guessing about the rest of your setup.   (I doubt it's a moment.js issue btw, probably something with react or something else.)

Comment: Well, kind of difficult to add a MVCE when it happens in React *Native*

Comment: could you help solve this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I learned recently that when using the chrome debugger, react native uses a different JS engine. The chrome JS engine is used during debugging, but JavaScriptCore is used otherwise. Per this article

http://ruoyusun.com/2015/11/01/things-i-wish-i-were-told-about-react-native.html

But for the actual issue with the dates, the JavaScriptCore engine doesn't seem to like parsing dates with a -. I had to use a regex expression to replace the - with a / and then all my date manipulation worked fine.

02-16-2016 09:04:23 is considered invalid

02/16/2016 09:04:23 is considered valid

Comment: Could you share the regex ?

Comment: Actually your answer helped me solve this issue. took me 2 hours to finally understand this. Thanks lol

Comment: replace(/-/g, '/')